# How do I yield to another request when using gunicorn with asyncio?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use the gaiohttp worker in Gunicorn with a Django app I'm developing with the following command:

```
gunicorn -k gaiohttp -b localhost:8080 myproject.wsgi
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to process requests concurrently - i.e. have 1 gunicorn worker process multiple requests concurrently. There are I/O bound operations which makes these requests slow.

I know an event loop is already running when I'm processing a request:

```
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.is_running() # True
        ...
```

Questions:

1. How can I perform an operation such as `yield from asyncio.sleep(10)` within my view code?

   ```
   class MyView(View):

       def get(self, request):
           # Raises AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
           yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
   ```
2. I can add tasks to the event loop, however they don't block while processing the request

   ```
   @asyncio.coroutine
   def simulate_work():
       yield from asyncio.sleep(10)

   class MyView(View):

       def get(self, request):
           # This runs simulate_work(), however, it doesn't block 
           # the response is returned before simulate_work() is finished
           loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
           task = loop.create_task(simulate_work())
   ```
3. I try to use futures, but the event loop is already running

   ```
   @asyncio.coroutine
   def simulate_work(future):
       yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
       future.set_result('Done!')

   class MyView(View):

       def get(self, request):
           future = asyncio.Future()
           asyncio.async(simulate_work(future))
           loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
           # Raises RuntimeError: Event loop is running.
           loop.run_until_complete(future)
           print(future.result())
   ```

Clearly there's something I'm not understanding about asyncio or gaiohttp.

How can I have `asyncio.sleep(10)` block for the current requests, but not block gunicorn from processing other requests?

Comment: Other gunicorn users mentioned the same thing as Andrew - see http://lists.gunicorn.org/user/74434.html - Unfortunately, I did give up and started using the Tornado framework instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot call coroutines from your wsgi application -- WSGI is *synchronous* protocol, as well as frameworks built on top of it (Django, Flask, Pyramid).

I've implemented `gaiohttp` worker but it's second class citizen in asyncio world. If you really need asynchronous HTTP server please try [aiohttp.web](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/v0.14.4/web.html).