# asyncio Future hangs indefinitely after result is set

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

Let's say there are two calls to the resolve method below using an identical value for `key`, before the result is set for an asyncio Future object.

- Call 1 sets the Future object on the queries attribute.
- Call 2 awaits the result for the Future to be set in Call 1 before resuming execution.

Instead, once the result is set from the Future in Call 1, Call 2 does not resume and instead hangs indefinitely. Am I missing something here?

```
import asyncio


class SomeResolver:
    queries = {}

    @classmethod
    async def resolve_from_cache(cls, key):
        if key not in cls.queries:
            raise KeyError
        else:
            fut = cls.queries[key]
            return await fut
            
    @classmethod
    async def resolve(cls, key):
        
        try:
            obj = await cls.resolve_from_cache(key)
        except KeyError:
            cls.queries[key] = asyncio.Future()
            
            # When resolved from other calls elsewhere...
            cls.queries[key].set_result(obj)
    
        return obj
```

Comment: check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222429/how-do-i-yield-to-another-request-when-using-gunicorn-with-asyncio

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you clarify what part of the link above that you're referring to exactly?